# Build libcurl.dll inside .exe?

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2012, dll, libcurl

What is the easiest way to include this curl.dll library inside the .exe file, so that the .exe doesn't ask for the .dll on an external computer, without the .dll file?
I'm using Visual Studios 2012.

Comment: @aring: this doesn't involve .NET.

Comment: @aring I'm using c++ not c#??

Comment: You're right, sorry about that!

Answer (score 3):

Build `curl` as a static library instead of a dynamic library. When you link against a static library, all the functions will be included into the executable directly, eliminating the need for an external `.dll`.

You can find instructions for how to do this all over the web, e.g. [here](http://swatrant.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-build-curl-static-library-with.html):

> Building cURL:
>
> 1. Run Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt from Start Menu > All Programs > Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition > Visual Studio
>      Tools. Or, Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt if you're using Visual
>      C++ 2010.
> 2. Navigate to winbuild sub-directory in cURL source directory, and issue following command:
>
>    ```
>    nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static WITH_SSL=static
>    WITH_DEVEL=C:\OpenSSL-Win32 VC=X ENABLE_SSPI=no ENABLE_IDN=no
>    ENABLE_WINSSL=no DEBUG=no MACHINE=x86 GEN_PDB=no ENABLE_IPV6=yes
>    ```

Comment: @user2723500: added instructions

Comment: I don't see why I need OpenSSL.

Comment: @user2723500: do you want to be able to download `https://`/`ftps://` URLs? If not, you can leave out the OpenSSL dependency.

Comment: "Navigate to winbuild sub-directory in cURL source directory" <-- which sub-directory? "VC=X, replace X" <-- replace with which number for VS2012?